# Groupby Sum and Flatten Multi-Row Index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a question which I think is very trivial but I am looking for a better way to code than what I think is possible.

I have the following dataframe:

| Index 1 | Index 2 | Index 3 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a1 | a11 | 1 |
| A | a1 | a12 | 1 |
| A | a2 | a21 | 1 |
| B | b1 | b11 | 1 |
| C | c1 | c11 | 1 |
| C | c2 | c21 | 1 |

I want to show all groupby results and flatten the dataframe to look like this:

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| a1 | 2 |
| a11 | 1 |
| a12 | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| b1 | 1 |
| b11 | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| c1 | 1 |
| c11 | 1 |
| c2 | 1 |
| c21 | 1 |

I can achieve it using multiple groupby on individual Index X column and then collating the results in a sequential order, but I am looking for more pythonic/efficient pandas operation which is possible but I am unaware of!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can just do a `stack` and `value_counts`:

```
index_cols = df.filter(like='Index ').columns
flattened_series = df[index_cols].stack().value_counts(sort=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> flattened_series
A      3
a1     2
C      2
a11    1
a12    1
a2     1
a21    1
B      1
b1     1
b11    1
c1     1
c11    1
c2     1
c21    1
dtype: int64
```

That just counts the values of the index columns; it doesn't actually sum the values of the `Value` column. Doing *that* would also be pretty simple:

```
flattened_summed_series = df.set_index('Value').stack().reset_index(level=0).groupby(0, sort=False)['Value'].sum().rename_axis(None)
```

Output:

```
>>> flattened_summed_series
A      3
a1     2
a11    1
a12    1
a2     1
a21    1
B      1
b1     1
b11    1
C      2
c1     1
c11    1
c2     1
c21    1
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```